# Jersey JAX-RS standalone server - how pass parameters to request handler?

Tags: java, jersey, server

I build a simple Jersey rest server, that handle a simple service.
In main class that start the server, i read properties file that i want to
provide/pass to jax handler classes.
The server works, i just have to make a way to share config parameters of
main class with handler of requests.
How i can do this ?

---

### The code of main, where i read de properties file one time only:

...

```
public HashMap resources;

// this start the listener jersey server...
String host="http://localhost/";
int port = 9998;
URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri(host).port(port).build();
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.packages(true, "br.com.myserver");
config.register(MyHandler.class);

// I WANT TO ACCESS/SHARE THIS WITH THE HANDLER -> MyHandler.class
resources.put("host_user","bla bla bla");

HttpServer server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config);

System.out.println("--Press Enter to STOP the server--");
System.in.read();
Server.stop(0);
System.out.println("Server stoped!");
...
```

---

### The code of MyHandler, where i want to access main properties:

```
@Path("myapp")
public class MyHandler
{
    @POST @Path("/testep")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String action1(@Context Request request, String json) 
    {
        // HERE I WANT TO ACCESS THE RESOUCES HASHMAP OF MAIN HERE
        // (how get main handler here).resources.get("host_user");

        // maybe access main class, or something like
        // the intention is to avoid the read of config at all requests here

        System.out.println("received event:" + json);
        return "event received " + json;
    }
}
```

Any ideas will be apreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any properties you configure the `ResourceConfig` using it's `property(key, value)`, will be accessible through the [`Configuration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration.html) interface which you can inject into your resource class.

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.property("host_user","bla bla bla");
...
@Path("myapp")
public class MyHandler
{
    @Context
    Configuration configuration;

    public String action1(@Context Request request, String json) {
        Map<String, Object> props = configuration.getProperties();
    }
}
```

**See Also:**

- [Configuration Properties with Jersey](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/12/configuration-properties-with-jersey.html) for some other ideas.

Comment: Thanks man, works fine! I search a lot but dont find the annotation that inject the config in the instance. thanks!

 @Context
    Configuration configuration;